# Flutter how to make a real time request

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello i'm writing a flutter application in which I have to print json data from the server.
The data are asynchronous which means always there is a new data which changes. For example if we have `{aa=5, bb=6}` after a period of time for example 1 minute the json data change to `{aa=10,bb=8}`. I want every time the data in server changes it should change in my application. I made a get request in which I was able to get data but only one time.

```
 Future<String> getData() async {

    http.Response response = await http.get(
         Uri.encodeFull("http://chicken20.pythonanywhere.com/jsonn"),
        headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
    print(response.body);
    data = json.decode(response.body);

  x1 =data['alm'].toString();
x2=data['alm'].toString();
 x3=data['co2'].toString();
   x4=data['hu'].toString();
 x5=data['temp'].toString();
   print('aaaaaa $x1,$x2,$x3,$x4,$x5');


    return "Success!";

  }
```

and this is how  i print data in my application interface

```
: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 1,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return new Column(
              children:<Widget>[

                Card(child:Text('alm :${x2}')),
                Card(child:Text('co2 :$x3')),
                Card(child:Text('hu :$x4')),
                Card(child:Text('temp :$x5')),

              ]);
        },
      ),
```

and this is my json format

```
{"alm":3,"co2":1,"hu":2,"temp":6,"th":11,"tm":14,"ts":13}
```

i need some help and thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use StreamBuilder [Flutter Docs - StreamBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html)